# JavaScript JQuery

Tags: iphone, navigation

I am modifying an existing navigation system for the iphone which does not support the hover class.  The menu should work on both a desktop computer and on iphone.

When I click on a menu item it shows and hides correctly.  It also shows and hides on hover. Great.  The problem is that when a user clicks on a link on the iphone and navigates to a different page, when the user comes back to the original page the menu is still open.  It remains that way until the user dutifully clicks the menu again to hide it whichisi not acceptable.

Can anyone help on this?  I have been at this a full day checking Stackoverflow with no results. My wife wants a divorce and my girl friend is unhappy too.

Here's the operative part of the css.

```
<div class="top_nav">
<ul id="nav" class="dropdown">
    <li <span class="dir">Desserts</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Pie</li>
            <li>Ice Cream</li>
            <li>Toppings
                <ul>
                    <li>Chocolate Sauce</li>
                    <li>Nuts</li>
                    <li>Whipped Cream</li>
                </ul>            
             </li>        
         </ul>
    </li>    
    <li>Dessert Wines</li>
    <li>Brandy</li>
</ul>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.top_nav').children("ul").children("li").click(function(e) {  //this works with click
        if($(e.target).closest("li").get(0) !== this) { return; }//anti-bubbling measure (try  without this line and see the effect) 
       $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).toggle();
    }); 
       $('.top_nav').children("ul").children("li").children("ul").children("li").click(function(e){ 
       if($(e.target).closest("li").get(0) !== this) { return; }//anti-bubbling measure (try  without this line and see the effect)     
    $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).toggle();   
    }); 
 });
```